# How to get records from a table with a string column where values of the string column starts with a given substring?

Tags: mysql, select

Example - Sub string is `"ab"` And if the contents are

```
abhi
babu
abdullah
```

Then after running the query I should be getting only the values

```
abhi 
abdullah
```

Even though value '`babu`' contains the sub string `ab`

Suppose the table name is `person` and the column name is `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator like this:

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE name LIKE 'ab%'
```

If you add `%` ahead of `ab` then `babu` will also come in result so only add `%` after `ab`.

Answer (score 1):

Use sql [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator

```
SELECT name FROM person WHERE name LIKE 'ab%'
```

above query return all name starting with `ab`, if you want to get names like `hiabhi` use like this

```
SELECT name FROM person WHERE name LIKE '%ab%'
```